Why does my list row separator disappear?
This is in Xcode 16.2 with the iOS 18 SDK, build target iOS 17.
I have some very simple code:
List {
    HStack {
        TextField("Some field", text: .constant("Hello"))
        Text("km")
    }
    Text("Hello")
}

When I run it the separator between the 2 list rows disappears beneath the TextField part:

When I remove the Text("km") line however, everything works as expected:
List {
    HStack {
        TextField("Some field", text: .constant("Hello"))
    }
    Text("Hello")
}


I have no idea what's going on here. Any suggestions?

Maybe compositingGroup() modifier can help here.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/compositinggroup()

SwiftUI attempts to automatically align elements in a row with the separator, but it may not always succeed.
You can manually specify exactly which element you want the separator to align with using the alignmentGuide modifier like this:
List {
    HStack {
        TextField("Some field", text: .constant("Hello"))
            .alignmentGuide(.listRowSeparatorLeading) { $0[.leading] } //  Telling that separators should be aligned with this component here

        Text("km")
    }

    Text("Hello")
}


Ah wow, this works. Thanks a lot!

Can you show me where you figured this out? Just reading the alignmentGuide docs doesn't really explain you can use it for this.

Here

SwiftUI's default separator placement relies on the layout information of the direct children of the List. When you only have HStack views, the layout system might not have enough information to reliably determine where to draw the separator, especially if the HStack content doesn't fully span the width of the list row.
you can get the same behaviour using this code
 let items = [
            Item(text: "Hello", unit: "km"),
            Item(text: "World", unit: "m"),
            Item(text: "Test", unit: "cm")
        ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ItemRow(item: item)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
      
    }


struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
    let unit: String
}



struct ItemRow: View {
    let item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Some field", text: .constant(item.text))
                Text(item.unit)
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}

